# Atlanta Sitecore User Group - July 14, 2022 ☀️

Tags: discussion, status-completed

**Date/Time (EST):** July 14, 2022 6:30 p.m.

**Date/Time (UTC):** July 14, 2022, 23:30

**Location:** [Perficient Dunwoody, 1200 Ashwood Pkwy, Atlanta, GA](https://goo.gl/maps/nRKmJ9w98ga7R7Sx6)

**RSVP:** https://www.meetup.com/atlanta-sitecore/events/286486793/

**Twitter:** [@AtlantaSitecore](https://twitter.com/atlantasitecore)

[image: Atlanta Sitecore User Group]

Mark your calendars for the next Atlanta Sitecore User Group meeting on July 14th, at 6:30 p.m., at the [Perficient Dunwoody Office](https://goo.gl/maps/nRKmJ9w98ga7R7Sx6)!

Dinner and drinks will be served.

We are looking forward to a great meeting! Everyone is welcome and we encourage you to spread the word!

### Raffle

Once again, [JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/) has provided us with a [dotUltimate](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotnet/) license to give away. At the end of the event, we will raffle off the license to one lucky attendee.

### Agenda

- 6:30 - 6:45: Food, drinks, and social time
- 6:45 - 7:00: Sitecore Community Update - [Corey Smith](https://twitter.com/sitecorey) ([Corey Smith Consulting](https://www.coreysmith.co))
- 7:05 - 7:35: Sitecore Headless DevOps Best Practices - [Luke Pace](https://www.linkedin.com/in/luke-pace/) ([Perficient](https://www.perficient.com/))
- 7:40 - 8:10: A React Crash Course for Sitecore Dinosaurs - [Brandon Bruno](https://twitter.com/BrandonMBruno) ([Sitecore](https://www.sitecore.com/))
- 8:15: Closing comments, raffle

### Presentations

#### Sitecore Headless DevOps Best Practices

**Speaker**: [Luke Pace](https://www.linkedin.com/in/luke-pace/) ([Perficient](https://www.perficient.com/))

What is Sitecore Headless? What is Git DMZ Flow and how do implement in Azure DevOps? [Luke](https://www.linkedin.com/in/luke-pace/) answers these questions and shows how to create build pipeline for Sitecore and Next.js; how to configure Azure PaaS for blue/green deployments; and how to build Azure release pipelines to deploy to Azure PaaS and Vercel.

#### A React Crash Course for Sitecore Dinosaurs

**Speaker**: [Brandon Bruno](https://twitter.com/BrandonMBruno) ([Sitecore](https://www.sitecore.com/))

I've been developing Sitecore solutions with MVC for more than 10 years, but thanks to headless and composable DXP architectures, I've become a Sitecore dinosaur. Join me, fellow dinosaurs, as we modernize our skills to ensure we're ready for the future.

This session acts as a (very) quick introduction to modern JavaScript and the React library from the viewpoint of a horribly-outdated backend developer. You will come away with a basic understanding of component-based development with React that can be applied to many headless frameworks and upcoming composable architectures.

Comment: Community Bulletin promotion begins in 6 days